# Понять причину краша ejabberd

Tags: erlang

Ставлю `ejabberd` с гитхаба `( github.com/processone/ejabberd.git )`
Установка с одной только директивой - поддержкой бд `postgres`, остальное дефолтно.

`aclocal -I m4
autoconf -f
./configure --enable-pgsql
make 
sudo make install`

После установки и запуска c дефолтной конфигурацией `Mnesia` получаю в логах `crash.log`:

`2015-12-23 17:17:32 =CRASH REPORT====
  crasher:
    initial call: application_master:init/4
    pid: <0.38.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {{bad_return,{{ejabberd_app,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',       ...{node_name_mismatch,[{ejabberd_app,db_init,0,[{file,"src/ejabberd_app.erl"},   ...{line,129}]},{ejabberd_app,start,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_app.erl"},{line,50}]}, ...{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,     ...273}]}]}}}},[{application_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,...134}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]}
    ancestors: [<0.37.0>]
    messages: [{'EXIT',<0.39.0>,normal}]
    links: [<0.37.0>,<0.7.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true 
    status: running
    heap_size: 610
    stack_size: 27 
    reductions: 166 
  neighbours:`

и

`error.log`:

`2015-12-23 17:17:32.223 [critical] <0.39.0>@ejabberd_app:db_init:125 Node name    ...mismatch: I'm [ejabberd@localhost], the database is owned by ['ejabberd@dofri']
2015-12-23 17:17:32.223 [critical] <0.39.0>@ejabberd_app:db_init:127 Either set   ...ERLANG_NODE in ejabberdctl.cfg or change node name in Mnesia
2015-12-23 17:17:32.224 [error] <0.38.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.38.0> with 0     ...neighbours exited with reason: node_name_mismatch in ejabberd_app:db_init/0    ...line 129 in application_master:init/4 line 134`

с конфигурацией на `postgres` тот же самый краш.

Эрланг:

`Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V7.1`

Comment: Возможно проблема не в эрланге, просто есть подозрение, что может быть и в нем. Почитал форумы - некоторые по похожей проблеме советуют попробовать сделать даунгрейд эрланга.

Comment: Пишет про несоответствии имени какой-то ноды. И предлагает одно из двух: установить ERLANG_NODE в ejabberdctl.cfg или изменить имя ноды в амнезии

Answer (score 1):

Sergey, насчет имени ноды вы правы - поменял. Для запуска правда оказалось несущественно :) 
Разобрался уже, проблема оказалась в зависшей сессии старого эрланга.

`ps aux | grep epmd
kill epmd_id`

Оставлю тут. Вдруг кому-то пригодится)